# How to switch to SuperDevMode from DevMode in GWT running through Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I am learning GWT for my internship that I start next week and I keep getting this error:

[image: Error Message when I run it]

I installed the GWT plugin and related engine through Eclipse Mars.  I am using the default code generated when you create a new project in Eclipse.  I also tried running the code of a tutorial from the GWT website and it generates the same error. Other posts mention removing `<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>` in the XML file but that just generates another error I cannot solve.

Is this caused by an error in my code or by how I set the project up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Project -> Properties`, find `Run/Debug Settings`, select your launch configuration and hit `Edit...` button. Go to `GWT` tab and change `Classic Development Mode` to `Super Development Mode`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the plugin from Google but the new one from Brandon.

https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin

He has a bunch of YouTube videos that display how to set up this plugin: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DU7ZQVLR5Zo&list=PLBbgqtDgdc_TqzA-qXrjgTFMC_6DKAQyT

Answer (score 0):

This is the old Dev Mode.

Today the Super Dev Mode is used for GWT developement. There are a lot resources on the web.

This one f.e.:

[Sencha GXT Documentation Super Dev Mode](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/guides/getting_started/sdm/SuperDevMode_Eclipse.html)

or

[GWT Tutorial for Beginners](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/gwt/gwt-tutorial-beginners/)

Search for questions about SDM here at StackOverflow. You will find a lot.